# Имя ViewBag не существует в текущем контексте

Tags: visual-studio-2015

Проект создан в VS 2012. Там нормально открывает и работает. Если открыть в VS 2015 он показывает ошибки, но все равно работает. С чем это может быть связано?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]